# Pytz call timezone by Name and Hour difference and convert one into another

Tags: python, time

How to extract the timezone list from pytz in hour format? I want to pass timezone cor conversion either by name or by the hours of difference. pytz only list timezones by names.

E.g Should be able to pass timezone as -5.5 for 'Asia/Kolkata'

```
import pytz

def DateTimetoUT(year,month,date,hour,minute,second,timzone):
        ltz = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
        lt = ltz.localize(datetime(year, month, date, hour, minute, second))
        return lt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)

# List of all timezone but only in name, not by hour difference 
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
        print (tz)


Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Asmara
Africa/Bamako
...
Asia/Kolkata # is -5.5 hr
```

Comment: you cant really do this ... you can certainly make a constant offset from utc timezone ... but you cannot readily map that back to a timezone name (mostly because of issues around daylight savings time)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Okay. How can I at least find the hour for a name?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime,pytz
def find_timezone_name(minutes_offset_from_utc):
    for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
            minutes = pytz.timezone(tz).utcoffset(datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()/60
            print(minutes,minutes_offset_from_utc)
            if minutes == minutes_offset_from_utc:                
                return tz

print(find_timezone_name(5.5*60)) # 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

be forwarned this will break because of daylight savings probably ... if you want to make a fixed timezone offset you can do

```
pytz.FixedOffset(minutes_offset_from_utc)
```